# Case 3 will not execute

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declare some variables you need
        // -->
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int endOption = 4;
        int chosenOption = 0;
        int countTo = 0;
        int factorialCount2 = 0;
        int lefty = 0;

        do {
            // Display the menu
            displayMenu();

            // Ask the user for one option
            // -->
            chosenOption = scan.nextInt();

            switch (chosenOption) {
                // Define four cases for different options. Don't forget "break".
                // -->
                case 1: 
                System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
                countTo = scan.nextInt();
                calcSum(countTo);
                break;
                case 2: System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
                factorialCount2 = scan.nextInt();
                factCont(factorialCount2);
                break;
                case 3: System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
                lefty = scan.nextInt();
                leftmostDig(lefty);
                break;
                case 4: System.out.println("Bye");
                break;
            }
        } while (chosenOption<endOption);
        scan.close();
    }

    /**
     * Print the menu
     */
    private static void displayMenu() {
        System.out.println("Please choose one option from the following menu:");
        System.out.println("1) Calculate the sum of integers from 1 to m");
        System.out.println("2) Calculate the factorial of a given number");
        System.out.println("3) Display the leftmost digit of a given number");
        System.out.println("4) Quit");
    }

    private static int calcSum(int addingTo){
        int sum = 0;

        for(int i=1;i<=addingTo;i++){
            sum = sum + i;
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of 1 to " + addingTo + " is " + sum);
        System.out.println();
        return sum;
    }

    private static int factCont(int number){
        int multiply = 1;

        for(int i=1; i<=number; i++){
            multiply = multiply * i;
        }
        System.out.println("The factorial of " + number + " is " + multiply);
        System.out.println();
        return multiply;
    }

    private static int leftmostDig(int num){
        int finalized = 0;
        while(num >=10){
            finalized = num/10;
        }
        System.out.println("The leftmost digit of " + num + " is " + finalized);
        System.out.println();
        return num;
    }
}
```

So, yes this is a lab I am doing for school.. the only one that will not execute is case 3. I am not sure what exactly is happening. I tried this while I was at work on an online compiler and it worked. Now when I transfer it to the actual program I run into a snag. Let me know what you think it might be as I am very perplexed by what could be.

Comment: What do you mean "will not execute" ?

Comment: Terrible title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your `leftmostDig` function contains a bug.  If `num` is greater or equal to 10, it will never exit (it never changes the value of `num`).   If you change it like the below, it will exit (and return the expected result).

```
private static int leftmostDig(int num) {
    int finalized = num;
    while (finalized >= 10) {
        finalized = finalized / 10;
    }
```